# Adb emu command not working sometimes

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, adb

I am using this command to send SMS to my emulator from the command line:

```
adb emu sms send 8888 Hello Android
```

The issue is the command does not work always; no error message but the SMS is not delivered to the emulator.

E.g I executed the command 9 times and I got only 4 SMSes ( 5 of them missing).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy:

First open the console and connect via **telnet** to the running emulator:

```
  telnet localhost 5554
```

then type this

```
 sms send phoneNumber textmessage
```

> ( `PhoneNumber:` is sender phone number, `textmessage:` text message)

Or

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:5554 --es sms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Comment: 1) I cant use the first one because I want to send sms from command line not from the telnet console.
2) I cant use the second option because that a command for sending outgoing sms from the emulator but I want to send sms into the emulator iself ( incoming sms)